# Jupyter notebook not found after install successfully completed on pip android how to fix this problem

Tags: jupyter-notebook

sh: jupyter: not found

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files $

How to fix it.Even installed liberty on pip will not shown after installed successfully, but it shows on the quick installed library,so please give me the way to solve this problem.

sh: jupyter: not found

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files $

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.